# Does the warren of the snares function as a critique of a specific group or behavior?

Tags: richard-adams, watership-down

While journeying to Watership Down, the Sandleford refugees encounter the warren of the snares. This warren has some distinctly odd ways of living, all stemming from how they accept that, in exchange for as much good food as they could ever want, some of their number are snared and disappear forever.

- They transport food to the main warren by carrying it in their mouths
- They have their own practices/traditions, and don't follow the rabbit god
- They don't have a leader
- They don't allow asking after a rabbit's location

In general, they act in ways that tip-toe around the snaring. They all know that some will be snared and die, but they don't speak of it and try to not think about it. Fiver (who acts as a voice of reason) soundly denounces this way of life.

Fiver criticizing the specific practice of carrying food by mouth:

> "I'll have nothing to do with it," answered Fiver in a low voice. "Dogs -- you're like dogs carrying sticks."
> <sub>Quote from Chapter 14: "Like Trees in November"</sub>

Fiver criticizing the warren as a whole:

> "The warren? You're going to the warren? You fools! That warren's nothing but a death hole! The whole place is one foul elil's larder!"
> <sub>Quote from Chapter 17: The Shining Wire</sub>

After that second quote, Fiver goes on a much longer rant tying together all the strange details of the warren into a neat explanation, all while criticizing each little detail. It's unfortunately far too long to quote here.

The specific strangeness of the warren, and Fiver's strong criticism of it, leads me to believe that the warren is a pointed critique.  I know that Adams didn’t intend for the story to have a deeper meaning, but he has biases, and a life background, and like any human this colors his thoughts and ideas. Could he have been unconsciously critiquing a group or behavior that he found unacceptable?

Does the warren of the snares function as a critique of a specific group or behavior?

Comment: Not sure if I'd say Fiver is acting as a voice of *reason* exactly. As usual for him, he *is* the only one with the insight to see that warren for what it is, but he doesn't express his insight in a very "reasonable" way, instead acting strangely, so that even Hazel thinks he's crazy, and nobody really takes him seriously until they have other evidence in front of their literal noses.

Comment: I could read into it a trade-off between freedom and security, but I would be very interesting to learn if there is any documented authorial intent.